# lldb & synthetic provider: follow pointer

Tags: c++, xcode, lldb

I have a custom class called `Values` that is a wrapper of arrays. For a given object `vFoo` of class `Values`, which contains an array of objects of class `Foo`, the `var format -T vFoo`command returns the following structure:

```
(MyNameSpace::Values) vFoo = {
  (void *) p = 0x0000000100204378
  (size_t) n = 2
  (MyNameSpace::ValueType) type = FOO
}
```

where `vFoo.p` is a pointer to the `array<Foo>` that contains 2 elements. I can access the array elements with the following command in the lldb prompt:

```
expression ((MyNameSpace::Foo*)vFoo.p)[0]
```

which returns

```
(MyNameSpace::Foo) $0 = "foo"
```

according to my summary provider.

I would like to write a synthetic child provider that returns something like:

```
(MyNameSpace::Values) vFoo = {
     (MyNameSpace::Foo) vFoo.p[0] = "foo"
     (MyNameSpace::Foo) vFoo.p[1] = "bar"
}
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do that. I read the [lldb data formatters page](http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html) and try to follow the structure given at the end of the page. I have also had a look at the bitfield and libcxx examples, but I can't find my way to the solution. Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Okay, I broke down my problem to the casting my pointer the an array and giving the array as a synthetic child. I tried in my get_child_at_index function, to return something in that spirit:

self.valobj.CreateValueFromExpression("p",'(std::array<MyNameSpace::Foo,2>*)vFoo.p')

but it's not working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the internal representation of the type `Foo`. You can get this from the SBModule using `self.valobj.GetFrame().GetModule().FindFirstType("Foo")`. Something like this will work with some poking around.

```
class Values_SynthProvider:
def __init__(self, valobj, dict):
    self.valobj = valobj
    self.num_elements = None

def update(self):
    self.num_elements = self.valobj.GetChildMemberWithName('n').GetValueAsUnsigned(0)

def num_children(self):
    return self.num_elements

def get_child_at_index(self,index):
    # Here you could switch on the value of Values::type to get the right type name to search for
    foo_type = self.valobj.GetFrame().GetModule().FindFirstType("Foo")
    return self.valobj.GetChildMemberWithName('p').Cast(foo_type.GetPointerType()).GetChildAtIndex(index,0,True)

def get_child_index(self,name):
    return int(name.lstrip('[').rstrip(']'))
```